# How to remove completely a media file from my website

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I switched my WordPress website from HTTP to HTTP, but I still have some media file loading with the HTTP protocol, which links to a mixed content blocking.

I remove the media files using HTTP from the server using FTP, and replace them with the correct media link HTTPS in my gallery.

I am using Elementor, and when I open the media, I can see that the link is in HTTPS in my media gallery. But when I load the website, it is still loading the old file in HTTP (at least trying to since it's not even on the server).

I purged all the cache and I still have the mixed content blocking, even when opening in Private Tab.

Can somebody help please ?

Thank in advance

Comment: It’ll be what you’re linking to on the page, force rewrite all rules using easy https redirection plugin

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, yes it worked thank you